# How to remove empty states from Activity Diagram in PlantUML?

Tags: plantuml

I am trying to diagram a game of blackjack in PlantUML to help document some code and I have empty Activity States that I would like deleted.

```
@startuml
skinparam defaultTextAlignment center
start
:Create Game \n(num_players, num_decks);
:Deal Cards\n(2 per player/dealer);
if (Dealer Shows Ace?) then (Yes)
    :Offer Insurance;
    if (Player takes insurance) then (Yes)
    else (No)
    endif
else (No)
endif
:Evaluate Hand;
:Next State;
@enduml
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The diamond nodes you highlighted are not states, but *merge* nodes, which correspond to the *decision* (if) nodes. The syntax of UML basically requires they be there.

Perhaps by adding a separate action "Set Insurance" (to remember that the player accepted it), the two merge nodes will make more sense?

```
@startuml
skinparam defaultTextAlignment center
start
:Create Game \n(num_players, num_decks);
:Deal Cards\n(2 per player/dealer);
if (Dealer Shows Ace?) then (Yes)
    :Offer Insurance;
    if (Player takes insurance) then (Yes)
    :Set Insurance;
    else (No)
    endif
else (No)
endif
:Evaluate Hand;
:Next State;
@enduml
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while looking for an answer to this problem, too. The magic words are `skinparam ConditionEndStyle hline`. The code

```
@startuml
skinparam defaultTextAlignment center
skinparam ConditionEndStyle hline
start
:Create Game \n(num_players, num_decks);
:Deal Cards\n(2 per player/dealer);
if (Dealer Shows Ace?) then (Yes)
    :Offer Insurance;
    if (Player takes insurance) then (Yes)
    :Set Insurance;
    else (No)
    endif
else (No)
endif
:Evaluate Hand;
:Next State;
@enduml
```

generates the following diagram:

[image]